# How Do I Concatenate PHP variable in SQL Query Then Concatenate Additional SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How Do I Concatenate PHP variable in SQL Query Then Concatenate Additional SQL Queries

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM news_posts WHERE status ="approved" AND user_id='.$user_id.'ORDER BY news_id DESC';
```

I got an error:

check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY news_id DESC' at line 132

Comment: add a space before `' ORDER`

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of concat the user_id, that will prevent you from SQL injection atacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM news_posts WHERE status ="approved" AND 
user_id='.$user_id.' ORDER BY news_id DESC';
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed? And why do you suggest a query that is widely open to SQL injections?

Answer (score 0):

try add a space before "ORDER"